# is it possible to mark, "brand" an apk?

Tags: android, apk, tracking

Good day all.
some times ago I asked about modifying an apk on the fly, the thing I would like to achieve is to track an ak from the download to the uninstall, via some track calls during its life.

the first thing first, of course is to find some way to "brand" it before the user downloads it on the phone.

things to take in advice are: 
I will not use the normal store to give the apk to people.
I can't make the user wait for 30 seconds during the download to make the build on the fly.
I can't ask users to "register, or login" I'm not able to arrive to that part to the server, too bad.

so far I have only guessd about modify the apk code on the fly, to search for a pattern in its code, and change it accordingly to my needs and save it on the database.

for example, lets say that in the values.xml there is a url like this:

```
 www.server.com?token=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

before servince the apk to the user, i search for the pattern `xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx` and change it with an alphanumeric value that i save on db, later, when the user go to the url via the apk, he will bring the token value and I could continue to track him again and again...

ok, this is the situation.. my question is simple... **any ideas**? am I mad... does someone already do this without any efforts and I'm try to reinvent the wheel?

Comment: Are you saying you just want a way to uniquely identify each device? If so, check this out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2785485/is-there-a-unique-android-device-id

Comment: indeed interesting, and could be a way if nothing better is coming, but as far as i can read there are tons of issues using any of those methods :/

Comment: You can't resign the APK with PHP, it would always require the jarsigner. The actual replacing isn't an issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't modify the apk, it would break the signing.
You would need to resign it. If you're able to resign it, you could easily change a value in an xml file of your choice.

It's rather easy to achieve with a bash script.

```
#!/bin/sh
sed -i ‘s/replace_key/actual_key/’ app/src/main/res/values/strings.xml
jarsigner -verbose -sigalg SHA1withRSA -digestalg SHA1 -keystore my-release-key.keystore my_application.apk alias_name
```

Comment: I like this, there should be no problems in resign it... I try to do some test about this. nic eidea.

Answer (score 0):

why dont you save the URL prefixes in DB instead of values.xml or in code. and when the user installs the apk, do a server hit in the Application class and get your tokens the first time and persist in DB. Since you say you already know the logic to generate the tokens fo reach user, so it should not be a big deal to generate the same token when users ask your server for it.